# How can I replace characters on the hexadecimal level in Notepad++?

Tags: replace, hex, notepad++

How can I replace characters on the hexadecimal level in Notepad++?

I have a file with some characters that can not be displayed in UTF-8 (problem with ANSI to UTF-8 conversion) and would like to replace these with the correct characters.

Notepad++ replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) can not distinguish these characters.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a hexadecimal code to find and replace in the *Find* dialog box, with *Search Mode* is set to *Regular expression*. Use the following search expressions as an example:

*Find what:* `\x{0A}` # Finds a line feed

*Find what:* `\x{0D}` # Finds a carriage return

[image]

Comment: For some weird reason this doesn't work for me.. It finds the binary data but replaces it with an empty string. Is it possible to replace the match with binary data?